# POST method on a form using POSTMAN

Tags: html, http, post, request, postman

I'm trying to create a http POST request using POSTMAN to this URL:

http://www.mfinante.ro/agentinume.html?pagina=domenii

on the codFiscalForm from HTML.

I set the input name=Oracle and judet=BUCURESTI and I'm receveing a piece of HTML, where I don't have the information I need (a HTML table form).

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the code for the form?

Comment: I'm sorrry, but the code is too long for a comment. If you will inspect the page,  you should look after the codFiscalForm.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of missing HTML table data in HTTP response is: The `POST /numeCod.html` request (action of `codFiscalForm`) is protected by `TS***` Cookies. In `POST /numeCod.html` request, if `TS***` Cookies, such as `TS018732dc`, `TS5d0550f8_27` etc. are missing or incorrect, the request would be rejected by server.

**When is `TS***` Cookies retrieved/updated?**

`TS***` Cookies are retrieved or updated when you open webpage `/agentinume.html?pagina=domenii`. Please note all HTTP responses when open `/agentinume.html?pagina=domenii` will set/update `TS***` Cookie, including responses of `.js`, `.png` files request.

When the result page is opened after submitting form, the `TS***` Cookies are updated again.

**How to confirm `TS***` Cookies are critical for retrieving data?**

On webpage, before click button `VIZUALIZARE`, you can open browser debug tool, such as Chrome DevTools, and delete one `TS***` Cookie in panel `Application - Cookies`. After that, click button `VIZUALIZARE` will lead to an HTML page without table data.

**Why Postman does not work even when `TS***` Cookies are defined in headers?**

Because `TS***` Cookies keep changing, it is very difficult (if not impossible) to get the latest valid `TS***` Cookies programmatically.